# Java: Null Pointer Exception in Savitch's book example?

Tags: java

Yes, I have read the EXCELLENT explanations that there are at Stackoverflow about the NPE, and I have understood what they meant. Yet, I found (I think I found) an issue about this NPE in one of the sample exercises on that textbook, that in fact, I used at Harvard long long time ago.

It is about the reference variable String line = null; as the explanations say, no object has been created while it is later on tried to be used as such (so I think), more precisely is tried to be accesed when  line = inputStream.nextLine( );. Here is the code and the question is how to fix that. I have tried instantianting an object but...not worked.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("original.txt"));
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("numbered.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem opening files.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String line = null;
        int count = 0;
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            line = inputStream.nextLine();
            count++;
            outputStream.println(count + " " + line.toString());
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

And yes, I tried to run it. I copied and pasted the code on a newly created project on Netbeans 7.3

Comment: Did you actually get NPE by running this very code?  If so, please post the details.

Comment: Yes, I tried to run the code long before posting. As I said, I tried several fixes and it would not compile.

Comment: Dereferencing: Possible Null Pointer.  on line String line = null  it says, "The assigned value is never used"

Comment: The warning is spurious. You could remove the assignment entirely so that the line reads `String line;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`line = inputStream.nextLine( );` doesn't try to access any object `line` : it assigns a value to the variable `line`. Thus, it doesn't need line to be not `null`.

Answer (score 4):

```
line = inputStream.nextLine( )
```

assigns a value to `line`. It does not try to read the current value of `line`, in particular by trying to call a method on it, so I don't see an NPE happening here. It's fine that `line` is `null` at this point, since its value is overwritten by the assignment.

You should try to prove your suspicion by actually running this code!

Comment: actually that is why I found the NPE because first it pointed it out at the beginning and second it would not let me compile. I am using Netbeans 7.3 So, of course I tried to run it.

Comment: `NullPointerException`s are runtime errors, not compile errors. What is the error message that your compiler gives? **The code in the question compiles.**

Comment: well now, despite the warnings it compiled. Yet, it caught the exception saying "problem opening files"

Comment: It caught a `FileNotFoundException`. That's something completely different.